# Singleton Return (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to pass an object by using Singleton, but when i print it in a new ViewController its gives me (null). When i NSLog the optionsSingle in the Viewcontroller1 it prints out the object.

Viewcontroller1.h

```
@interface PrivateViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
{
    rowNumber *optionsSingle;
}
```

Viewcontroller1.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    optionsSingle = [rowNumber singleObj];
    optionsSingle = [devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
}
```

Viewcontroller2.h

```
@interface SelectVideo : UITableViewController<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
{
    rowNumber *optionsSingle;
}
```

Viewcontroller2.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    optionsSingle=[rowNumber singleObj];
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", optionsSingle.selectedRowNow]);
}
```

row.h

```
@interface rowNumber : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *selectedRowNow;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selectedRowNow;

+(rowNumber *)singleObj;

@end
```

row.m

```
@implementation rowNumber
{
    rowNumber *anotherSingle;
}

@synthesize selectedRowNow;

+(rowNumber *)singleObj
{
    static rowNumber * single=nil;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(!single) {
            single = [[rowNumber alloc] init];
        }
    }
return single;
}

@end
```

Comment: By convention class names start with a capital letter. Files names of a class are the same as the class name, where possible. This prevents confusion and allows others to more easily understand others code.

Comment: I doubt that this use of a singleton is warranted. Basically Singletons should be used very sparingly, not just for passing an value between objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your singleton like this:

```
static id shared_ = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    shared_ = [[[self class] alloc] init];
});
return shared_;
```

Also in viewController1.m:

```
optionsSingle = [rowNumber singleObj];
optionsSingle = [devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

the second line makes the first line useless.

You are also trying to log something that, by the looks of it, you are never creating or setting. I can't see where you are actually setting 'selectedRowNow' - you should override the init method in your rowNumber class to create the mutable 'selectedRowNow' array.

Comment: You don't need `[self class]`, just `self`. In a class method, `self` is the class.

Answer (score -1):

You will create a singleton like this easy way

in you .h file write given bellow code

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *selectedRowNow;
}
+(MySingleton *)sharedInstance;
```

the next step is in .m file write bellow code

```
@implementation MySingleton
static MySingleton *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
            return sharedInstance;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
}
    return self;
}
```

After that you can define this bellow code in .pch file or constant file for reduce code

```
#define AppSingleton [MySingleton sharedInstance]
```

then call like

```
AppSingleton = [devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: That is overkill and the current best practice is to use `dispatch_once`.